# Combine two filters into a single call

Tags: php, filters

Is it possible to combine two filters?

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_columns', function($columns) {
    $columns['author'] = 'User';
    return $columns;
});

add_filter( 'manage_edit-recipe_columns', function($columns) {
    $columns['author'] = 'User';
    return $columns;
});
```

I want to rename the 'author' column on all pages with posts; but I don't want to apply it to every single custom post type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the received arguments and the return values are the same, yes, you can combine them.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-post_columns', 'my_columns_callback' );
add_filter( 'manage_edit-recipe_columns', 'my_columns_callback' );
function my_columns_callback( $columns ) {
    $columns['author'] = 'User';
    return $columns;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @butlerblog!

Comment: Not a problem!!